# Loop through complex JSON with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

guys i have the following JSON

```
 "detailed_statistics": [
      {
        "internal_key": "CORR",
        "divider_name": "Corrosion Features",
        "plots": [
          {
            "chart_title": "Feature Location on Wall",
            "chart_type": "pie",
            "radius": "50%",
            "data": [
              {
                "plain_naming": "Internal",
                "hex_colour": "#d0320e",
                "value": "386"
              },
              {
                "plain_naming": "External",
                "hex_colour": "#0000ff",
                "value": "504"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "internal_key": "MILL",
        "divider_name": "Manufacturing Features",
        "plots": [
          {
            "chart_title": "Feature Location on Wall",
            "chart_type": "pie",
            "radius": "50%",
            "data": [
              {
                "plain_naming": "Internal",
                "hex_colour": "#d0320e",
                "value": "737"
              },
              {
                "plain_naming": "External",
                "hex_colour": "#0000ff",
                "value": "54"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "internal_key": "DENT",
        "divider_name": "Dent Features",
        "plots": [
          {
            "chart_title": "Feature Location on Wall",
            "chart_type": "pie",
            "radius": "50%",
            "data": [
              {
                "plain_naming": "Unclassified",
                "hex_colour": "#000000",
                "value": "53"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "internal_key": "WELD_ANOM",
        "divider_name": "Weld Anomalies",
        "plots": [
          {
            "chart_title": "Feature Location on Wall",
            "chart_type": "pie",
            "radius": "50%",
            "data": [
              {
                "plain_naming": "Unclassified",
                "hex_colour": "#000000",
                "value": "2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "internal_key": "OANOM",
        "divider_name": "Complex Anomalies Not Otherwise Classified",
        "plots": [
          {
            "chart_title": "Feature Location on Wall",
            "chart_type": "pie",
            "radius": "50%",
            "data": [
              {
                "plain_naming": "Unclassified",
                "hex_colour": "#000000",
                "value": "51"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

what i want is to dig into the data [] and get lets say the value and store it into a separate array and from there i want to pass it to a pie chart as a parameter in order to built a pie. the way i am doing it i get the response as below:

```
(7) ['386', '504', '737', '54', '53', '2', '51']
```

however what the response i want is :

```
(5) [['386', '504'],[ '737', '54'], '53', '2', '51']
```

how i achieve the above result ? the first 2 values needs to be grouped together as the belong to the same "family" if that make sense. i want to use either forEach or for loop Javascript/ typescript

they way i am doing it and doesnt work for me is:

```
  this.myData[0].detailed_statistics.forEach(value => {
    console.log("this is the value", value.plots)
    value.plots.forEach(val => {

      console.log("is this the titles?", val.chart_title)
      this.plotTitles.push(val.chart_title)
      this.plotRadius.push(val.radius)
      
      val.data.forEach(plt => {
        this.plotPlainName.push(plt.plain_naming)
        this.plotValue.push(plt.value)
        this.plotColor.push(plt.hex_colour)
      })

    });


  })
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this to retrieve the values in the form that you want:

```js
const result = this.myData[0].detailed_statistics
  .map(stat => stat.plots
    .map(plot => plot.data
      .map(data => data.value)
    )
  )
  .flat()
  .map(values => values.length === 1
    ? values[0]
    : values
  )
```

If you want to stick with something similar to what you have, but where the `plotPlainName`, `plotValue` and `plotColor` arrays all follow the requested format, then you could do something like this:

```js
this.myData[0].detailed_statistics.forEach(stat => {
  stat.plots.forEach(plot => {
    this.plotTitles.push(plot.chart_title)
    this.plotRadius.push(plot.radius)

    this.plotPlainName.push(
      plot.data.length === 1
        ? plot.data[0].plain_naming
        : plot.data.map(data => data.plain_naming)
    )

    this.plotValue.push(
      plot.data.length === 1
        ? plot.data[0].value
        : plot.data.map(data => data.value)
    )

    this.plotColor.push(
      plot.data.length === 1
        ? plot.data[0].hex_colour
        : plot.data.map(data => data.hex_colour)
    )
  })
})
```

Comment: thank you, i will give it a go tomorrow see if it works. note that the json might return more or less data so i want to do that automatically what i mean is that the Json might needs to return ``` (5) [['386', '504','21'],[ '737', '54'], ['53','4'], '2', '51'] depends on how many data it has. the format of the json would be like the one i have posted above though. the amount of data will differ

Comment: Yes this should handle that. It will just remove the value from each nested array if there is only one value.